# How to change my primary Gmail email address?

Tags: gmail

I recently created 5 Gmail email addresses. I didn’t know that the 1st email address would become what Google calls “the primary” email address associated with my Google account. I want to change “the primary” email address to one of the other Gmail email addresses. I googled how to do this. The step by step guides provided don’t seem to help me. How do I do this?